# How do I fix the Killing Floor 2 issue where it shows a black screen on startup with music playing in the background?

Tags: technical-issues, killing-floor-2

I have a problem with a freshly installed *Killing Floor 2* on my laptop (Steam version). Upon launching the game, it shows a black screen instead of the main menu. I can hear the main menu music in the background, so I think the game is running but not displaying properly. My laptop has a GeForce MX150 GPU and runs on Windows 10. How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I found out that it was caused by the default values in my `KFEngine.ini` file for `Min/MaxAllowableResolutionX/Y` being set to `0`. To fix this, I followed these steps:

I made a backup of the `KFEngine.ini` file (in case I need to restore it in the future), which is located in this directory:

`%USERPROFILE%\Documents\My Games\KillingFloor2\KFGame\Config\`

Then, I opened `KFEngine.ini` using a text editor and replaced the `[WinDrv.WindowsClient]` section with this:

```
[WinDrv.WindowsClient]
AudioDeviceClass=XAudio2.XAudio2Device
MinAllowableResolutionX=768
MinAllowableResolutionY=768
MaxAllowableResolutionX=1366
MaxAllowableResolutionY=1366
MinAllowableRefreshRate=30
MaxAllowableRefreshRate=240
ParanoidDeviceLostChecking=1
AllowJoystickInput=1
```

I changed the values of `Min/MaxAllowableResolutionX/Y` (previously `0`) to match my monitor's native resolution (1366 × 768). For example, if your monitor has a resolution of 1920 × 1080, you should use these values:

```
MinAllowableResolutionX=1080
MinAllowableResolutionY=1080
MaxAllowableResolutionX=1920
MaxAllowableResolutionY=1920
```

I saved the file and restarted the game. The black screen issue should now be gone.

I got the idea to fix it this way from this Reddit comment: "[Killing Floor 2 Stuck at low resolution bug](https://www.reddit.com/r/killingfloor/comments/hpp7u0/killing_floor_2_stuck_at_low_resolution_bug/hh2r6a0/)", where someone used it to fix a different bug related to low resolution. It seems that both bugs are caused by the same issue with the `KFEngine.ini` file.

---

If the issue persists, here are some other things you could try.

Try toggling between fullscreen and windowed mode.

To do this, open the `KFSystemSettings.ini` file (but back it up first), which is located in this directory:

`%USERPROFILE%\Documents\My Games\KillingFloor2\KFGame\Config\`

Look for the text `Fullscreen=` under `[SystemSettings]` and toggle it to be `True` (fullscreen) or `False` (windowed), e.g., `Fullscreen=True` if initially `false` and vice versa. Note that there are many variables named `Fullscreen` in `KFSystemSettings.ini`. You need to edit the one under the `[SystemSettings]` section. In my case, it's line 36, the first instance that appears in the file.

If the above works but it's in windowed mode, try toggling the `Borderless=` setting in `KFSystemSettings.ini`.

Search for the text `Borderless=`, located under `[SystemSettings]`, and then set it to be `Borderless=True`. This should set it to borderless windowed mode.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work for me. I followed these instruction exactly and still just get a balck screen with music.

Comment: @Robert To investigate this further, what were the `Min/MaxAllowableResolutionX/Y` values prior to you editing it?

Comment: They were all 0. I use a 1920x1080 resolution so I used those values but still got a black menu. However, I have managed to play since then, one of these changes must've made a difference: 1) I reinstalled the game 2) I disconnected my VPN 3) I started the game with the -windowed flag. One of those three must've worked because the game started normally

Comment: @Robert Thanks for mentioning that. I think it's number 3. I've added this information to my answer. Are you still playing in windowed mode? Because you can set it to borderless windowed mode.

Comment: Yes, but only for starting up. I still have issues where the screen is black sometimes but at least in windowed mode I can kill the game with the task manager. Once I see the game loads the main menu properly I can alt+enter to get fullscreen